# Codecing vectorial field qgis

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, vector, fields-attributes, encoding

I have vectorial data that I have loaded in qgis setting as UTF-8. I was checking if the values of field in atribute table is standartized. So I am creating a script to do it. However, when I print list of field all alfa atributes values are printed so stranged. Look below:

BaixÃ£o Lagoa Grande
BaixÃ£o Mundo Novo
BaixÃ£o da Bandeira
BaixÃ£o da Panela
BaixÃ£o da Planta
BaixÃ£o da Serra
BaixÃ£o da Solta
BaixÃ£o das Queimadas
BaixÃ£o do Campestre
BaixÃ£o do FeijÃ£o
BaixÃ£o do Pontal
BaixÃ£o do Umbuzeiro
BaixÃ£o do Xique-Xique
BaixÃ£o dos Caboclos
Vereda da Espadeira
Vereda da espadeira

I encoded this values to 'latin' and they become well when I print one by one element of my list. For example: Baixão Lagoa Grande.

However I need one list with all of them. So I made this:

```
idx = l.fieldNameIndex('nome')
values = l.uniqueValues(idx)
lista_nome = []
for v in values:
    print str(v.encode(encoding='latin1'))
    lista_nome.append(str(v.encode(encoding='latin1')))
print lista_nome
```

The result has been all characters so messy again, like the firt print that I showed (for example: BaixÃ£o Lagoa Grande)

How to correct this characters?

Comment: Can you load the layers with Latin1 instead of UTF-8?

Comment: I know that vector was produced in UTF-8. This is the reason to load it like this.

Comment: @underdark I did what you advice me. The problem continued. I haven't understanded why encode of string in list are so wrong. When I print them alone they are well written.